# c# always on top exception

Tags: c#, fullscreen, always-on-top

I used this code

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication52
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
    static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
    static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
    static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
    const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetWindowPos(this.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
    }
}
```

but some applications remain at the top. I turned from the task manager but sometimes I want to start again.I can't run. How I fix it ?

[image: like that]

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx

Comment: Some topmost windows are more topmost than the top of the topmost because they just get to the top :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov creative solutions :)

Comment: Why use that code??  Just set the TopMost property of the form instead of re-inventing the wheel?  `this.TopMost = true;`

Comment: it does'nt work. i still try close it